# React Router - Route With Optional Params Not Working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am using react and react-router. In my react router configuration, I want to add a route that will accept the following URL: http://localhost:7000/example/GUID where GUID is the user's GUID that is logged in at that moment.

I am using WebPack.

I went to the react-router documentation: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#path-syntax

But that does not work for some reason, maybe I am missing something.

This is my react router configuration:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from "react-router";
import Main from "../containers/main.js";
import Home from "../containers/home.js";
import Example from "../containers/exampleComponent.js";

var Routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path="/example(/:guid)" component={Example} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

module.exports = Routes;
```

When I go to http://localhost:7000/example, it works fine, it loads the example component.

But When I go to http://localhost:7000/example/GUID, it does not work. In fact, it does not load anything then. According to the documentation, the "()" in the route path indicates that it is optional.

Is there anything else that I need to do to make this work? I've been scratching my head on this one...

**EDIT**: Please see my github project here: https://github.com/FredM7/react-base
The project includes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am also using path like this `path: 'cn/*/cid/(:catZeroId)(/:catOneId)(/:catTwoId)'` it works flawlessly for me.

you might be having react-router version issue, i am using `"react-router": "^3.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.6",`

or you can create https://jsbin.com/, https://plnkr.co/ to simulate your case.

Comment: Hi @veetesh - Please see my github project that has this problem :): https://github.com/FredM7/react-base

Comment: @FrederikMoller you need to add `<base href="/" >` in your index.html or you need to setup some web container which serve your static files [express static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: @FrederikMoller you need to add `<base href="/" >` in your index.html or you need to setup some web container which serve your static files [express static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

also you need to add path="/" for your main route `<Route path="/" component={Main}>`

Comment: thanks! adding <base href="/" > to my index.html worked fine! But can you explain why we need to add that? Do you also have a reference to awebsite? Because I could not find anything that indicated that I need to add that <base href="/" >

Comment: No working with Latest   "react-router-dom": "^4.2.0", "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",